# Google App script: toString() with formating

Tags: google-apps-script

I like to output a number based on a format. Looks like string.format is not supported in Google App script.  May I know what options do I have? Here is a sample code to explain my need.

```
function test(){
  var r=1/3;
  var st=r.toString();
  Logger.log(st.Format("0.00"));  // I like to see 3.33 instead of 3.333333333
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function test(){
  var r=1/3;
  var st= Utilities.formatString('%.02f', r);
  
  Logger.log(st);  // output will be 0.33
}
```

In App script you have Utilities like

```
// " 123.456000"
Utilities.formatString('%11.6f', 123.456);

// "   abc"
Utilities.formatString('%6s', 'abc');
```

For more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatstringtemplate,-args

Answer (score 1):

`Utilities.formatString()` is a right idea. But just in case, here is a RegExp solution:

```js
var r = 1/3;
var st = r.toString().replace(/(\.\d\d)\d+/, '$1');

console.log(st); // '0.33'
```